# update and insert mysqli table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to check if the `leaguename` name already exists if it does then check if it is higher than the existing score. if its higher then replace the `quizscore` else insert the `leaguename` and `quizscore` into the table league_quiz.

The code seem to insert the values in my table, but it do not seem update if the name is equal to previous and the score is higher?

I get this error:

> Warning: `mysqli_num_rows()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, string given in

My code:

```
<?php

$name = (string)$_POST['name'];
$score = (string) $_POST['score'];

$link = mysqli_connect("mysql12.gigahost.dk","username","password","dirts_mysql");

$query = "SELECT leaguename, quizscore FROM league_quiz WHERE  leaguename = '$name' AND quizscore < '$score'";

if(mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
    mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE league_quiz SET quizscore = '$score'");
} else {
    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO league_quiz (leaguename, quizscore) VALUES ('$name', '$score')") or die(mysqli_error($link));
}

?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: Also you should run the query $query = mysqli_query($link, "select here");

Comment: Why are you casting strings to strings? Why aren't you escaping your values using [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)? I really hope this isn't live on the internet because it could be cracked in seconds.

Comment: i'll take a look on the bind_param and it is not live.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_num_rows expects the result of a query and not the string of the query itself.
Firstly you must execute your query :

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
```

and then you can count the number of rows

```
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: first who knows that mysqli needs link for connection for query.

Comment: Please, remove that link to w3schools for the sake of all humanity. [The lessons there are severely damaging](http://w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Between those two:

```
$query = "SELECT leaguename, quizscore FROM league_quiz WHERE  leaguename = '$name' AND      quizscore < '$score'";

if(mysqli_num_rows($query)) {
```

Have you tried to write this code?

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

and then use mysqli_num_rows on the result of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Try the followowing:

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
...
```